# Getting "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" when creating record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am porting an old Rails 3 application to Rails 4.0.15 and everything seems to be going fine except that whenever I try to create a record (even in Rails console) I am getting the above error (undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass).

I am over-simplifying things a little here but what I did was to create a new app (`rails new xxxx`) then copy the `app/` and `db/` tree over from the old. I used the same db. routes.rb and Gemfile were adjusted manually.

One of the models is Contact:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :phone, :address
end
```

In `rails console` I get the following when I type `Contact.create`:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.5)
irb(main):001:0> Contact.create
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:113:in `block in read_attribute'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:111:in `fetch'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:111:in `read_attribute'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:19:in `id'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:344:in `remember_transaction_record_state'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:282:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:267:in `save'
    from /home/wucolin/.gem/ruby/gems/protected_attributes-1.0.3/lib/active_record/mass_assignment_security/persistence.rb:46:in `create'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Best case scenario: I'm hoping someone would see this and go "Yeah, that's easy to fix. All you do is..."

However, I would be quite happy if someone could point me in the right direction or where to start.

Thanks all for you time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "attr_accessible" feature is gone in Rails 4. I suggest to not use the gem, there have been many reports of issues.

Rather than pushing "protected" into Rails 4, install the [`strong_parameters`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) gem and backport the strong parameters feature in Rails 3.

It is definitely a more appropriate approach.

Comment: Yeah, that's on my general "todo" list. As it turns out v1.0.3 of protected_attributes was the problem. Don't know what the specific problem was but upgrading to v1.0.8 has allowed me to carry on. Thanks.